# RavenDb MapReduce filter by Id

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I have the simplest MapReduce index:

```
    public class LawDisadvantageRatingIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<LawDisadvantage, LawDisadvantageRatingIndex.IndexResult>
    {
        public class IndexResult
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public long Value { get; set; }
        }

        public LawDisadvantageRatingIndex()
        {
            Map = (lawDisadvantages => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                                       from vote in lawDisadvantage.Votes
                                       select
                                           new
                                               {
                                                   Id = lawDisadvantage.Id,
                                                   Value = vote.Value,
                                               });

            Reduce = (lawDisadvantages => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                                          group lawDisadvantage by lawDisadvantage.Id
                                          into agg
                                          select new
                                                     {
                                                         Id = agg.Key,
                                                         Value = agg.Sum(x => x.Value)
                                                     });
        }
}
```

Here is the typical query:

```
_documentSession.Query<LawDisadvantageRatingIndex.IndexResult, LawDisadvantageRatingIndex>().Single(x => x.Id == lawDisadvantageId);
```

When I query it with filtering by Id I get the following exception:

> "Url":
>   "/indexes/LawDisadvantageRatingIndex?query=__document_id%253ALawDisadvantages%252F1&start=0&pageSize=2&aggregation=None",
>   "Error": "System.ArgumentException: The field '__document_id' is not
>   indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed\r\n   at
>   Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.AssertQueryDoesNotContainFieldsThatAreNotIndexes()

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600252/querying-a-ravendb-index-on-id-given-not-indexed-error-how-to-fix) seems relevant.

P. S. I have removed my previous similar question by mistake - sorry for that.

**Update.** Thanks to Matt Warren suggest I came to the implementation without Reduce part:

```
public class LawDisadvantagesForListIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<LawDisadvantage>
{
    public class IndexResult
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
   }

    public class LawDisadvantageForList
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long Rating { get; set; }
        public long CommentsCount { get; set; }
    }

    public LawDisadvantagesForListIndex()
    {
        Map = lawDisadvantages => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                                  select new { Id = lawDisadvantage.Id };

        TransformResults = (database, lawDisadvantages) => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                                                       select new
                                                                  {
                                                                      Id = lawDisadvantage.Id,
                                                                      Title = lawDisadvantage.Title,
                                                                      Description = lawDisadvantage.Description,
                                                                      Rating = lawDisadvantage.Votes.Sum(x => x.Value),
                                                                      CommentsCount = lawDisadvantage.Comments.Count
                                                                  };
    }
}
```

Here is a typical usage:

```
 var lawDisadvantages =
                _documentSession.Query<LawDisadvantagesForListIndex.IndexResult, LawDisadvantagesForListIndex>().
                    As<LawDisadvantagesForListIndex.LawDisadvantageForList>().
                    ToList();
```

I like this implementation but the dissappointing part is I have to calculate Rating and CommentsCount on the fly (I would prefer to store these values in index).

P. S. I still think there is a bug in RavenDb related to my first index.

Comment: Erm, now I'm more confused. You're setting up and index that can only query on Id. What type of queries do you want to perform against the Id field, there might be a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: @MattWarren, I have added a typical query to the question

Comment: @MattWarren, You are right, I don't query by Id in this case but I don't know how to create an index which doesn't contain any fields. Hm... Looks I am definitely do something wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the bug, but the more interesting question is why are you doing things this way at all?

I assumne you have docs that are something like this:

```
public class LawDisadvantage
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class Vote
{
    public int Value
    ....
}
```

If you just make your index like this:

```
public LawDisadvantageRatingIndex()
{
       Map = (lawDisadvantages => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                            select new
                              {
                                   Id = lawDisadvantage.Id,
                                   ValueSum = vote.Values.Sum()
                              });
}
```

You don't need the Reduce part as you're grouping on `Id` which is redundant. The Id field is unique per-document. In effect you're pulling the individual Votes from out of their parent doc and then grouping them back into the same groups they were originally in.

**Update**
You've changed your question a bit and I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do.

You ask

> I like this implementation but the dissappointing part is I have to
>   calculate Rating and CommentsCount on the fly (I would prefer to store
>   these values in index).

Actually that probably preferable. If you stored the values in the index you'd be taking up space with information that you don't appear to be querying against. It's better to only store data in the index that you actually need to query against, otherwise it's wasted space.

The transform results section of the index runs in-memory and so it will be very fast to calculate the results. Plus it will be only calculating them when they are needed for the result of a query, rather than for every document.

How many `Votes` and `Comments` do you expect to have within one `LawDisadvantage` document?

Comment: I don't want to have just Map as it will return the whole document with thousands of Votes. So I have to add TransformResults any way. But you are right - Reduce part is redundant here (see update). Thank you!